# How to set HTTP Status Code in Authorize Attribute in ASP NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an `ASP .NET Core 3.1` application. I am using `Identity` authentication. An user can have over 100 rights in the application. For user authorization I have extended the `Authorize` attribute. See below my code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public IList<EnumPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params EnumPermission[] permissions)
    {
        Permissions = permissions;
    }
    private void SetResult(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.Result = context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
                ? (IActionResult)new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                : (IActionResult)new ForbidResult();
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        var accepted = this.Permissions.Any(x => user.HasPermission(x));
        if (!accepted)
        {
            SetResult(context);
        }            
        return;
    }
}
```

And below is `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
         var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
             .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/NotAuthorized/";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
            options.LoginPath = "/Auth";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });        
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I want to use the above attribute on both controller types (MVC and API)
I have a problem when I use the attribute as in below example for API routes

```
[CustomAuthorize(EnumPermission.AddUsers, Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
```

The validation authorization works fine but the client API response is `HTML`(nore exactly the content of the page Auth/AccessDenied). This is happen when the authorization fails before to execute my code (itseems that the response is set by default Authorize attribute)
How can I return `JSON` format for API requests and `HTML` for `MVC` requests, and how can I set status to 403 when the user is logged but he/she does not have enough permissions and 401 otherwise? What should I set/override?

Comment: It looks to me your attribute mixed two things up. `Authorize` attribute is a metadata executed by Authorization middleware where the filter interfaces are MVC types that are executed later in the pipeline. What you might need is a custom policy with custom requirements which validates user roles as well as permissions, so check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy) out.